# Getting multiple values in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql

If I have a table that lists names and ages then can I run a single query that will give me all names of people with a particular age.

e.g.

```
name      age
----------|-------
alice      20
bob        21
chris      20
dave       23
eric       26
fred       29
greg       20
```

I want my query to return a list, separated by a comma, of all people who are aged 20.

e.g.

```
select (concat(name,',')) from people where age='20'
```

And this outputs:

```
alice,chris,greg
```

Obviously I could just do:

```
select name from people where age='20'
```

And then loop through the results in PHP but I am trying to do all of this in a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name from people where age='20'
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from people where age='20'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM people
WHERE age='20'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/name.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: interesting approach - not sure if it work - but incomplete: how to get the file back into PHP? (anyways - I think the accepted answer is much easier)